# Which psychiatric disorders currently have objective, neuroimaging-based diagnostic methods?

Tags: neurology, diagnosis, psychiatrist-psychiatry

For which psychiatric conditions is it possible currently to view someone's brain through neuro-imaging to conclude that a brain condition is present?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?